# Excel VBA Dynamic Combo Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 Combo boxes in columns A1 through A5 and in column 6 I have a plus and minus button which are just command buttons with a plus sign and minus sign as text on them

When pressing the plus button I have code that copied the entire row and inserts it below.  When pressing the minus button the entire row is removed (you are unable to remove the first row as there must always be one present.

Here is the code for inserting and removing a row:

```
Public Sub InsertRow()
   
Dim newBtnAddress As String

'Find out which button was clicked
newBtnAddress = ActiveSheet.Pictures(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Pictures(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy

'Insert a copied row below the button that was clicked
Range(newBtnAddress).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Select
Selection.insert Shift:=xlDown

'Deselect the copied row
Application.CutCopyMode = False   

End Sub

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim deleteAddress As String
        
deleteAddress = ActiveSheet.Pictures(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
    
'Find out which button was clicked
Range(deleteAddress).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

I have experimented with both the Active X Combo and the forms combo, this is what I have found.

When using the Active X Combos the combos don't get copied to the new row when adding a row, however they delete fine (if they are there) when the row is removed.

The Forms Combos are the opposite.  They get copied when you add a row but not deleted when removing a row.  They also don't have a change event like the Active X Combos.

I'm wondering if anyone has done any dynamic generation of combos and the approach they took and why they behave differently from each other?

Comment: How  about using data validation instead?  It's easier to work with in this  kind  of situation.

Comment: Hi Doug, yeah I considered that, although I forgot to mention that Im populating my combo boxes from ADO recordsets.  If I use Data Validation I would need to put these in a sheet somewhere and link the dropdowns to that.  I also make use of the Change events on the combo boxes to filter the ones to the right as the user makes selections